# Failure to load swirl

Tags: r, swirl

I am trying to load swirl `library(swirl)` in RStudio on 64-bit Windows 10, and I am running across an error.
The error code is:

```
library(swirl)
```

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘swirl’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):

And then I tried:

```
"swirl" %in% installed.packages()
[1] TRUE
```

Could you please suggest some possible solutions to this problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: When you installed `swirl`, were there any error messages? Have you tried reinstalling it? I suspect some bits and pieces may be missing (e.g. `RCurl`).

Comment: I think there isn't any problem in installing itself. It returns: > install.packages("swirl")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/swirl_2.4.3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 344263 bytes (336 KB)
downloaded 336 KB

package ‘swirl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in (location of the packages)